Test keeps failing even though component unmounted in the app
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { act } from 'react'
import Notifications, { defaultNotificationTime, defaultOpacity, queuedNotificationTime, fadeInTime } from '../Components/Notifications';
import { NotificationContext } from '../Context/NotificationContext';

const renderNotification = (notifications: string[], setNotifications: jest.Mock) => {
    return render(
        <NotificationContext.Provider value={{ notifications, setNotifications }}>
            <Notifications />
        </NotificationContext.Provider>
    );
};

beforeEach(() => jest.useFakeTimers());
afterEach(() => jest.useRealTimers());
const setNotifications = jest.fn();

describe('Notifications Component', () => {
    test('renders with no notifications', () => {
        renderNotification([], setNotifications);
        expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification')).toBeNull();
    });

    test('displays a notification and hides it after the default time', async () => {
        const notifications = ['Test notification'];
        // Initial render with notification
        renderNotification(notifications, setNotifications);
        // Verify the notification element is in the document
        expect(screen.getByTestId('notification')).toBeInTheDocument();
        act(() => {
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(fadeInTime);
        });
        expect(screen.getByTestId('notification')).toHaveStyle(`opacity: ${defaultOpacity}`);
        expect(screen.getByTestId('notification')).toHaveTextContent(notifications[0]);
        act(() => {
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(defaultNotificationTime);
        });
        expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification')).toHaveStyle(`opacity: 0`);
        act(() => {
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(fadeInTime * 2);
        });
        expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });

});

Test Keeps failing at expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
It says the component is still found.
 Notifications Component › displays a notification and hides it after the default time                                       
                                                                                                                                
    expect(element).not.toBeInTheDocument()                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                
    expected document not to contain element, found <div data-testid="notification" id="notification" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;"><p>Test notification</p></div> instead                                                         

      41 |             jest.advanceTimersByTime(fadeInTime * 2);
      42 |         });
    > 43 |         expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification')).not.toBeInTheDocument();

It should have been unmounted from the following component.
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo, memo, useContext } from 'react';
import { NotificationContext } from '../Context/NotificationContext';
import './Style/index.css';

export const defaultOpacity = 0.85;
export const defaultNotificationTime = 2500;
export const queuedNotificationTime = 2250;
export const fadeInTime = 750;

const Notifications: React.FC = () => {
    const { notifications, setNotifications } = useContext(NotificationContext);
    const [fadeIn, setFadeIn] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [currentNotification, setCurrentNotification] = useState<string | null>(null);

    // Manage CSS styles for the notification
    const notificationCSS = useMemo(() => ({
        opacity: fadeIn ? defaultOpacity : 0,
        transition: `opacity ${fadeInTime / 1000}s ease-in-out` // Transition duration and easing
    }), [fadeIn]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (notifications.length === 0) {
            setCurrentNotification(null);
            return;
        }
        setCurrentNotification(notifications[0]);
        const fadeInTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            setFadeIn(true);
        }, 0); // trigger shortly after setting the notification to ensure fade in effect
        const notificationShowTime = notifications.length > 1
            ? queuedNotificationTime
            : defaultNotificationTime;
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setFadeIn(false);
            const exitTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                setNotifications((prev: string[]) => prev.slice(1));
            }, fadeInTime); // Ensure this timeout matches the CSS transition duration
            return () => clearTimeout(exitTimer);
        }, notificationShowTime);

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(fadeInTimer);
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [notifications, setNotifications]);

    return (
        <>
            {currentNotification && (
                <div id='notification' data-testid='notification' style={notificationCSS}>
                    <p>{currentNotification}</p>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default memo(Notifications);

I have tried numerous amount of timers, some very extremely large number but it just doesn't dismount in the test, but it successfully dismounts in the app. So I don't think timer is the issues here.

Because setNotifications  function is a mock function with default implementation. It will not "update" the notifications state if I guess correctly.

Don't mock the unit of code you are trying to test... mock its external dependencies. Because you are providing a mock setNotifications callback no state anywhere in the tested components is actually updated, e.g. const { notifications, setNotifications } = useContext(NotificationContext); is never an updated notifications value so for the tests that try to remove notifications the notifications "state" from the context is still populated.
In your case here I believe there's nothing that needs mocking. You can create a notifications provider component that uses and provides a real React state that can be updated.
Example:
const NotificationsProvider = ({
  children,
  notifications
}: React.PropsWithChildren<{ notifications: string[] }>) => {
  const [baseNotifications, setBaseNotifications] = React.useState(notifications);

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider
      value={{
        notifications: baseNotifications,
        setNotifications: setBaseNotifications,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
};

const renderNotification = (notifications: string[]) => {
  return render(
    <NotificationsProvider notifications={notifications}>
      <Notifications />
    </NotificationsProvider>
  );
};

describe('Notifications Component', () => {
  test('renders with no notifications', () => {
    renderNotification([]);
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification')).toBeNull();
  });

  test('displays a notification and hides it after the default time', async () => {
    const notifications = ['Test notification'];
    // Initial render with notification
    renderNotification(notifications);
  
    // Verify the notification element is in the document
    expect(screen.getByTestId('notification')).toBeInTheDocument();

    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(fadeInTime);
    });
    expect(screen.getByTestId('notification'))
      .toHaveStyle(`opacity: ${defaultOpacity}`);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('notification'))
      .toHaveTextContent(notifications[0]);

    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(defaultNotificationTime);
    });
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification'))
      .toHaveStyle(`opacity: 0`);

    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(fadeInTime * 2);
    });
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('notification')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

